# Babel 7 does not polyfill Promise, Fetch and some JavaScript files (like in a vendor file) in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, webpack-4, babel-loader, babel-polyfill

I upgraded to [Babel 7](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration). It works fine in evergreen browsers like [Opera](https://www.opera.com/) and Chrome. But in IE11, Promise and Fetch API are not polyfilled in JavaScript. When I manually polyfill them, I then see a strange issue where a vendorXYZ.js file still has ES6 code (SCRIPT error). How do I fix this?

Comment: Was this caused by updating babel 6 to 7, or was it caused by query-string being upgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel 7 has an issue where it does not polyfill Promise and Fetch API. This not a problem in evergreen browsers as they support these natively. But it is a huge problem in IE11 which lacks native support. I could not find a way to make Babel polyfill them. The workaround was to polyfill them myself. I used [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) to polyfill Promise, and [whatwg-fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) to polyfill fetch.

I believe a trend will soon start where npm package publishers will not bother providing a built-version of their code in ES5. Anyways, it is common not to have Babel transpile packages in node_modules. So, you may have a JavaScript file written in ES6 but being passed to IE11, which causes a problem. I recommend glancing at the vendor file or whatever file webpack outputs to and try to see if you have figure out what package has ES6+ code. I personally had an issue with [query-string](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string#readme) version 6. The fix is to either downgrade to a different version with ES5 or transpile the code with babel-loader.

Comment: Why the downvote? Someone woke up one day, saw a question with no code and said "let me downvote". That makes no sense. How else can I express this? By music notation?